# string matching against 2nd and 3rd occurence of the word

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin, pattern-matching

I've a stringSome = "this is a string and it is a string and it is a new string."
wordList = [ a, string, string, and, is]

i want to iterate it sequentially and it should result with giving the indices.

result should be start indices sequentially=
8, 10, 30, 37, 44

a, s, s, a, i

the first and only indices are pretty easy with only calling indexof however, i'm unsure how to go on about searching if a string is repetitive.

```
val getIndicesOfAllWords: MutableList<Triple<String, Int, Int>> = mutableListOf()
val stringSome = "this is a string and it is a string and it is a new string."

val wordList = listOf<String>("a", "string", "string", "and", "is")
for (word in 0 until wordList.count()){
    val firstIndex = stringSome!!.indexOf(wordList[word])
    val matchLength = wordList[word].length
    getIndicesOfAllWords.add(Triple(wordList[word], firstIndex, matchLength))        
}
```

Comment: updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i'm reaching to an answer with the following code..
will be optimizing it shortly, if any better solution, or if i've done something wrong, pls advise.

```
val getIndicesOfAllWords: MutableList<Triple<String, Int, Int>> = mutableListOf()

for (word in 0 until wordList.count()){
    if (getIndicesOfAllWords.count()==0) {
        val firstIndex = desc!!.indexOf(wordList[word])
        val matchLength = wordList[word].length
        getIndicesOfAllWords.add(Triple(wordList[word], firstIndex, matchLength))
    } else{
        val firstIndex = desc!!.indexOf(wordList[word], getIndicesOfAllWords[word-1].second+1)
        val matchLength = wordList[word].length
        getIndicesOfAllWords.add(Triple(wordList[word], firstIndex, matchLength))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you find a word save its current index in a HashMap, for each word you want to search for if it is found in that map start searching from the last index + 1 otherwise start searching from the start.

Comment: i'm here saving the values to a triple, extension of a pair.
string -> matched word
int -> first index
int -> last index.

could you guide more as in how i'd go about it a bit more?